# How to order elements in Firebase using AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, angularfire2

What is the proper way to reorder items in Firebase?
Using AngularFire2

[image]

Few years ago I did that using ordering by priority. There was a method `.setWithPriority()` and even a hidden property `$priority` that you could set and elements would be automatically reordered. Then, **priority** was going to be deprecated.

Please help me to figure out how to do it correctly nowadays

Comment: you can use `db.list('/collections', ref => ref.orderByChild('name'))`. check the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md)

Comment: I know about ordering by child. I was asking about priority. But seems like priority is deprecated

Comment: The doc says `_Anything you can achieve with orderByPriority you should be doing with orderByChild_`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very detailed list of the OrderBy-Property for firestore queries, [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: I'm asking about firebase not firestore. But thanks for your answer